# How can the visibility of a button in a form be changed dynamically using x++ code?

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, form-control

How can I change the visibility of my button control `MyButton`?

I have a form `MyForm` where I want to set the visibility property for my `MyButton` button control.
I used this code in the form's `init` method:

```
public void init()
{
    MyTable myTable;
    ;

    while select myTable where myTable.UserId == curUserId()
    {
        if (myTable.FlagField == NoYes::Yes )
        {
            myButton.visible(true);
        }
        if (!myTable.FlagField == NoYes::No )
        {
            myButton.visible(false);
        }
    }

    super();
}
```

The property `AutoDeclaration` of `MyButton` is set to `Yes`. But when I open the form, I get the following error:

> "Failure initializing FormButtonControl object."

I think I have to use the FormButtonControl class, but I no have idea how to do that.

Comment: You code looks like it is executed before the `super()` call. Have you tried putting the code after the `super()` call?

Comment: FH-Inway Thanks.
The code is longer than what you see
In my method I have even more lines of code that make things different than what you see in the post. 
Your advice was helpful, If you want ,post your answer, I will accept your answer.
I appreciate your help

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FH-Inway's answer is correct from a code-perspective, but I want to comment that what you're doing is incorrect and won't function properly unless your `mineTable` only has 1 matching record.

Currently as written, when the form is instantiated, you basically loop over `mineTable` and toggle the `myButton` visible and hidden over and over for every record `where mineTable.UserId == curUserId()` , then the form is displayed and whatever the last record happens to be.

That's the difference between `while select [table] where [clause] {[code]}` and `select [table] where [clause];`.

If you only have one record in that table you should change it to:

```
MineTable mineTable;

super();

select firstonly mineTable where mineTable.UserId == curUserId();
if (mineTable)
{
    if (mineTable.FlagField== NoYes::Yes )
    {
        myButton.visible(true);
    }
    if(!mineTable.FlagField== NoYes::No )
    {
        myButton.visible(false);
    }
}
else
{
    throw error("Record not found or whatever your error should be");
}
```

Comment: First of all +1 for taking the time to give the asker additional hints to improve the code. I edited the question before I saw your answer and changed this part of the code for similar reasons, but since this part of the code has no relevance to the question, I didn't feel the need to explain the change in my answer. But I think your approach is better, so I will edit the question to restore this part of the code so your answer makes sense to future readers.

Comment: All the `if`statements are bogus. just use `myButton.visible(mineTable.FlagField);`

Comment: "That's the difference between while select [table] where [clause] {[code]} and select [table] where [clause];"   it should probably be clarified that even without the 'while' a select statement may return more than one record you just won't see it unless you .next() the record buffer

Answer (score 2):

The controls of a form are initialized by the `super()` call in the form's `init` method. To change the properties of a form control, it has to be initialized first, so you have to place the code that changes the property after the `super()` call.